# How can I write a MapBy type in typescript 3.9.7

Tags: typescript

I want to write a `MapBy<T, K>` type under typescript like:

```js
type A = { propA: string, propB: number }
type MapAByPropB = Map<A, 'propB'>;
// {
//   [key: number]: A[]
// }
```

First I tried following but errors occur said `'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'`. Though I have ensure that **K** is only the keys of number, string or symbol type props.

```js
type ObjectKeyType = number | string | symbol;
type KeyTypeProps<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends ObjectKeyType | undefined ? key : never;
}[keyof T];

type MapBy<T, K extends KeyTypeProps<T>> = {
  [key in Required<T>[K]]: T[];
};
```

You can have a try in [online playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIBVwQAoCcD2YDOAeBAfFALxQDeAUFFANoDW8UAlgHZQMgYBmUCAugC5e9eHygQAHsAgsAJtijosENKDggoAHygBXORC6sIsqAH52jISwgA3FQG4KAXxGce-RxVCQoAWQCGYABCIAAM+AA0sOJSMvKw8EiQSjj4BESklNSuzGwAShAAjjpMaMZpNDB8gsJ8jk6e3tABwSAAjJHRktJyCupJqJiphBlQBcWl5YSVYt1xCikqavBUZuSr1NkcuWNFJWWyFVU1CDR1G1BOq1a2DhQUkmAYqlAAxhgs2MBQALaBISQoJ0YDEevF+sgUngRgAKGz+AA2Ogg2CEpz4UQ4ADl-D8IEIYABKIQtEIdBBRGAZIhZKBlYA6NBseFIlEAOgOOleEBhMP8r1eUVejMJJBpF3en2+21IwrQrhxePOm2YPBh2wAhMRSHpZAYjLJRbSVUw1Rr+a9XHwjRcVQB6O1QACiaEwaCgGAFjIUAAsVBAopwdFBrMYoAADPkCq1QfwKdGi0hncNQYAYVMQBEI1MKJjfV7+NjWOzugBG0HDxZU4dtmwtMaTypVl1rDtTfqg2Fx0BUbo9XrQvv9tfrHD4bLAOmwPphcsJjhVVxV9MZbAtC8uUTITljClJ7WBBHnzkcQA), the error keeps until v4.3.5. But this project can't upgrade ts to v4 for some reason.

Any ideas **why this error occurs** and **how to avoid it in ts v3.9.7**?

### Update

Use condition type can avoid the error:

```js
export type MapBy<T, K extends KeyTypeProps<T>> = Required<T>[K] extends PropertyKey
  ? {
      [key in Required<T>[K]]: T[];
    }
  : never;
```

But the problem still exist: ts can't get that the key in `MapBy<T, K>` **is `PropertyKey`**, and think it can be `never`. We need to tell ts it can never be `never` using `as` when use `MayBy` type. Check the above plaground for detail code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create `ObjectKeyType`, there is a built in type `PropertyKey`.

In order to fix this error in earlier versions of TS, just add conditional type:

```js
type ObjectKeyType = number | string | symbol;
type KeyTypeProps<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends ObjectKeyType | undefined ? key : never;
}[keyof T];

type MapBy<T, K extends KeyTypeProps<T>> = Required<T>[K] extends PropertyKey ? {
  [key in Required<T>[K]]: T[]; // ok
} : never

type Result = MapBy<{ age: number }, 'age'> // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AaQiAKuaBeKAOwFcBbOCAJygB8oBnYSgS0IHNaGRyB7AGwDcAKFCQoGbLgAKlHmHoAeLAD4oBAN5CoUANoBrTFFZQDIHgDMoWALoAuK-szWoEAB7AIhACb1YiFOiYOGJ0xN4Q5qwQXlAA-CaG9oQQAG5UwgC%20jmaWNsIiuFAAsgCGYABCIEoANOIu7p4%204kHSsvJKyqoEAEoQAI7EzJTRHTpozm4e3r4yclSgEnFQmtrZRoRQvQNDIypj1nYO1gJQAPSnUDx6QhlQSalUQgVivfTEfMBqxWWVCupQJTYECSZAo1AytQA5ICIJDVOdLtcgA)

**UPDATE**

```js
type KeyTypeProps<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends PropertyKey | undefined ? key : never;
}[keyof T];

type MapBy<T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>, K extends KeyTypeProps<T>> = {
  [key in Required<T>[K]]: T[]; // ok
}
type Result = MapBy<{ age: number }, 'age'> // ok
```

I have used an extra restriction: `T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>`

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this and it make the error disapear. But when comes to usage, since the `MapBy` can be never, you need to declear the type using `as` to tell the ts that it can never be `never`. It is a little stupid and troublesome. Any idea to avoid this?

And can you tell why this error occurs?

Comment: @Valen please provide full example with `never`

Comment: please check the playground link in the question, I have updated the example here.

Comment: Your new added restriction `T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>` limit the varible `T` type. In fact I wish it can be all posible object, like `Record<PropertyKey, any>`

Comment: If value can be `any` type, then this type `Required<T>[K]` is impossible, because `T` values should be only string or numbers in order to be used as a key for iteration

Comment: `[key in Required<T>[K]]`, after `in` keyword you can only use `PropertyKey` type. Otherwise, how would you iterate over objects?

Comment: That is why we have `K extends KeyTypeProps<T>`. It make sure that `T[K]` is `PropertyKey` type.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work that way. TS is about static typing, not dynamic

Comment: There is nothing about dynamic. Also, it works in v4.3.5.

Comment: @Valen, yes, you are right. I can't explain it

Comment: I think it might be related to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#template-string-type-improvements